# issue with flutter launcher icons, after successfully installed it doesn't show the launcher icons in my android device

Tags: android, flutter, assets, appicon, launcher-icon

[image]

```
here is my pubspec.yaml file , here I am added correct what documents says,
```

[image]

```
here is my project structure and icon added folder
```

here I had successfully generated launcher icons from there flutter packages , and also in the terminal it shows , icons successfully generated, but when I install app on my device it doesn't show app icon , here I checked the android manifest file and mipmap folder there also I can see my launcher icon inside mipmap folder , but it doesn't show it on device

Answer (score 0):

I think due to the cache of the build your facing the problem. so clear the `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` it will work.

Comment: checked that still its not showing

Comment: any other solution for adding app icon in flutter